# django model filter question

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which I need to filter based on different conditions. I want to avoid having to write complicated nested conditions and fitting a model filter onto every situation.

Is there anyway to concatenate or combine the filter() arguments into a variable and then put that variable as a set of filter arguments like this?:

```
db_table.objects.filter(variable_of_arguments)
```

being equal to:

```
db_table.objects.filter(
    (Q(first_name__icontains=search) | 
     Q(last_name__icontains=search)), 
     foo = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but may be you can do it with 2 parameters:

```
param1 = Q(first_name__icontains=search) | Q(last_name__icontains=search))
param2 = {'foo', False}

db_table.objects.filter(param1, **param2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a variable number of arguments and pass them in as follows:

```
q = Q(first_name__icontains=search) | Q(last_name__icontains=search)
p = Q(first_in_line=True) | Q(last_in_line=True)

args = [q, p]

kwargs = {
    'foo': True
    'bar': False
}

db_table.objects.filter(*args, **kwargs)
# Equivalent to:
#
# db_table.objects.filter(
#    Q(first_name__icontains=search) | Q(last_name__icontains=search),
#    Q(first_in_line=True) | Q(last_in_line=True),
#    foo=True,
#    bar=False
# )
```

Now you can use whatever logic you want to build up `args` and `kwargs` and the call to `filter()` will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that's been around for a while that might help: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1679/